# Populating cascaded dropdown when javascript is disabled in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a cascaded dropdown on a MVC form. I want the child dropdown to be populated at server side if the JS is disabled in the browser. I tried following scenarios

1. Using a button of type Submit next to parent drop-down and on click of it load the child drop-down at server side.

   Problem: Client side validations are fired (not sure  why and how when JS is disabled) and hence              will not hit the server method
2. Using a input type button, but then i wont get the other form values to re-populate the form on server side.

Comment: You should be able to stop the button validating by adding a class of `cancel` to it although I have found that a [submit button attribute](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=724) in the back end is very useful to tell the controller what action to process.  You can the cancel the validation for that action using `ModelState.Clear();`

Comment: Adding Cancel doesn't help

Comment: Html5 validations can be still working, even if javascript is disabled